# pushViewController & popViewController animation no longer functioning in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, ios14

For some reason this code:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Is behaving the exact same way as:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

The behavior is a non-animated push. I am not sure why the animation parameter is no longer functioning. It worked properly in iOS 13. Is this a bug?

Upon further research, I also noticed that in `viewWillAppear`, `ViewWillDisappear`, and `ViewDidAppear` that the `animated` property is false. Overriding the functions with:

```
super.viewWillAppear(true)
```

does not make any difference.

For further context, I am using a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` that displays a `UITabBarController` that contains a `NavigationController` inside of it. The view in the `UINavigationController`, and all of the pushed views, are where I am experiencing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed my problem!

Turns out that in my `UITabBarController` I had this line of code in my `viewDidAppear` function:

```
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
```

instead of `viewDidAppear`! As a result, the nested `UINavigationController` had animations off. Unsure why this worked in iOS 13, but it shouldn't have!

Key takeaway: remember to properly override your `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` functions!

Going to keep this in here in case someone else runs into this issue.